# segfault on second calling of opendir

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, opendir

**Some background:**

I am writing a module for nginx (web server) that allows for on-the-fly setting of root directories in a shared environment. I have a directory that contains other directories, one for each hosting user; given a directory path relating to a requested domain I need to determine which user it belongs to.

```
--public_dir
---user_1
---user_2
----com/example/www/_public/
---user_3
```

www.example.com is converted to com/example/www and the function should return "user_2"

**The problem:**

I successfully do this by opening public_dir, traversing it, and checking each 1st level directory (users) for the existence of com/example/www/_public/ and caching the result. All runs as expected the first time the function is called. The second time segfaults when attempting to open public_dir again (it has been successfully closed in the previous function call):

```
#define NGX_SHARED_ENV_SHARED_DIR "/var/www/public/"
#define NGX_SHARED_ENV_PUBLIC_DIR "_public"

char* ownerFromDir(char *dir){
    char *owner;
    char fullPath[strlen(NGX_SHARED_ENV_SHARED_DIR)+strlen(dir)+128];
    struct dirent *e;
    struct stat sb;

// ------------ERROR IN HERE----------------------------

    fprintf(stderr, "Before opendir\n");
    DIR *sharedDir = opendir(NGX_SHARED_ENV_SHARED_DIR);
    fprintf(stderr, "After opendir\n");

// -----------------------------------------------------

    if(sharedDir){
        while((e=readdir(sharedDir))!=NULL){
            //is the entry a directory?
            if(e->d_type!=DT_DIR){ 
                continue;
            }
            if(strcmp(e->d_name, ".")==0 || strcmp(e->d_name, "..")==0){
                continue;
            }
            // build a path to check for /var/www/public/userX/com/example/www/_public
            snprintf(fullPath, sizeof(fullPath), "%s%s/%s/%s", NGX_SHARED_ENV_SHARED_DIR, e->d_name, dir, NGX_SHARED_ENV_PUBLIC_DIR);
            stat(fullPath, &sb);
            //if a matching directory is found then copy the entry name into owner
            if(S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){ 
                int len = 1 + (int) strlen(e->d_name);
                owner = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
                free(owner);
                memcpy(owner, &(e->d_name), len);
                break;
            }
        }
        closedir(sharedDir);
    }
    return owner;
}
```

gdb isn't very helpful even when compiling with gcc -g for debug flags

```
Breakpoint 1, ownerFromDir (dir=0x603450 "com/example") at ngx_module.h:43
43  char* ownerFromDir(char *dir){
(gdb) step
45      char fullPath[strlen(NGX_SHARED_ENV_SHARED_DIR)+strlen(dir)+128];
(gdb) step
48      fprintf(stderr, "Before opendir\n");
(gdb) step
Before opendir
49      DIR *sharedDir = opendir(NGX_SHARED_ENV_SHARED_DIR);
(gdb) step
50      fprintf(stderr, "After opendir\n");
(gdb) step
After opendir
51      if(sharedDir){
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, ownerFromDir (dir=0x60b4a0 "com/example2") at ngx_module.h:43
43  char* ownerFromDir(char *dir){
(gdb) step
45      char fullPath[strlen(NGX_SHARED_ENV_SHARED_DIR)+strlen(dir)+128];
(gdb) step
48      fprintf(stderr, "Before opendir\n");
(gdb) step
Before opendir
49      DIR *sharedDir = opendir(NGX_SHARED_ENV_SHARED_DIR);
(gdb) step

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a99df2 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

EDIT: backtrace

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7a99df2 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a9b446 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7a9dfc5 in malloc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7ad651b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000400aea in ownerFromDir (dir=0x60b4a0 "com/example2") at ./ngx_module.h:48
#5  0x0000000000400cb2 in ownerFromDom (domain=0x40116c "example2.com") at ./ngx_module.h:82
#6  0x0000000000400f3f in testOwner (domain=0x40116c "example2.com", expect=0x401150 "user2") at ./ngx_module.c:45
#7  0x0000000000400e27 in runTests () at ./ngx_module.c:29
#8  0x0000000000400d0b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe708) at ./ngx_module.c:10
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: My first question is, at the crash can you please provide a backtrace? My second question, what's happening between the two calls? Maybe you have some stack overwrite problems somewhere else? And my third question is why do you have code in a header file?

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg 1. backtrace added 2. in between I run a test function that passes a domain name to the domain / directory converter and then to this function, comparing the answer (I'll test more directly to exclude stack overwrites) 3. I'm self-taught and relatively new so had assumed a header file was used for shared code :) (I'll go read up on it)

Comment: Re 2. repeated direct calls to the function still result in the same segfault

Comment: What's the value of `_DIRENT_HAVE_D_TYPE`?  We really don't need to see the conditional compilation here; it just makes your code bigger and your question harder.

Comment: For interest's sake: _DIRENT_HAVE_D_TYPE signals if the struct returned from readdir() contains the type of the entry. Only the name (d_name) and inode number (d_ino) are requisite POSIX return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does:

```
        if(S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
            int len = 1 + (int) strlen(e->d_name);
            owner = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
            free(owner);
            memcpy(owner, &(e->d_name), len);
            break;
        }
```

and that leads to:

```
return owner;
```

You've freed the memory so the `memcpy()` is invalid (accessing memory that you have no right to access) and the return is at the very least dangerous and arguably invalid (you're passing back a pointer to freed memory).

Remove the `free()` in this code.  Who knows what's going wrong in the calling code, but a moderately plausible guess is 'you `free()` the returned value', which is a double free, which is also a serious no-no.

As written, the `memcpy()` could easily corrupt your heap; a double free could corrupt your heap.  So, with two sources of heap corruption, you're very likely to get a crash somewhere as a result, and `opendir()` does memory allocation, so it is a plausible victim.  If you did a memory allocation before that, it would probably crash instead.

Comment: Thank you, I had it in there earlier when building parts of the function so I wouldn't have a leak and forgot to remove it.